# iPhone local backup failing: "Could not back up the iPhone [phone_name] because the backup session failed."

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, backup

**Problem**
When syncing an iPhone over WiFi by pressing the "Backup Now" button on the iPhone's menu in Finder, the operation fails a few seconds later:

A dialogue with an "OK" button pops up and says:
"Could not back up the iPhone [phone_name] because the backup session failed."

**Software versions**
(Not really that important, because this error has been seen in many past versions for several years.)

- macOS: Ventura 13.6
- iOS: 16.7.1

**Solutions that don't work:**

- Rebooting the iPhone

**Web pages with solutions that don't work:**

- [Apple Discussion Forums: Backup session failed](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8585473): Advice from 2018 that doesn't work.
- [iMobile: iTunes Backup Session Failed? 6 Solutions to Fix it](https://www.imobie.com/ios-system-recovery/solutions-to-itunes-backup-session-failed.htm): Windows-specific advice that references iTunes
- [Apple Support: If you can't back up your iOS or iPadOS device to a computer or restore it from a backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203271)